# How can I scroll so that a specific element becomes at the middle of visible region of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of list items and I want to put every specific item in the middle of the visible region of their parent div. So the first element can scroll to the middle I added some dummy items before it. (and also to the end of list items). and this is my function:

```
function scrollToMiddleView(elem) {
    if (elem) {
        var main = $("#container");
        m = main.scrollTop() + main.height() / 2;
        t = main.offset().top + m;
        main.animate({scrollTop: elem.offset().top - t}, 500);

    }
}
```

I test it on a sequence of elements. It works for some elements and doesn't work for some others. I works when the scrollbar is at the top. I want each element precisely located in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that worked. the `main.scrollTop()` must be subtracted from `main.offset().top`, and then the result must be subtracted from `elem.offset().top`.

```
function scrollToMiddleView(elem) {
    if (elem) {
        var main = $("#container");
        m = main.height() / 2;
        t = main.offset().top - main.scrollTop() + m;
        q = elem.offset().top - t;
        main.animate({scrollTop: q}, 500);

    }
}
```